# Remote Notification: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: android, genexus, onesignal

tengo un problema en un ambiente de test al querer enviar una notificacion, el resultado de ejecutar el evento `GeneXus.Common.Notifications.SendNotification` es:

> [{"Id":"   1","Type":1,"Description":"The request was aborted: Could
> not create SSL/TLS secure channel. - (0)"}]

No se si me está faltando algo en algun archivo de *config*.
Estoy usando **OneSignal** como proveedor de notificaciones.
Si ejecuto la [API de OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications) en el servidor de *test* funciona, pero no creo que sea la misma url que usa el evento `SendNotificacion`.
En mi ambiente de desarrollo funciona bien.

Comment: El ambiente de desarrollo conecta con la misma API de notificaciones? Lo otro que revisaría es las diferencias en el software base entre los ambientes. Es posible que se esté usando una versión de TLS que el ambiente productivo no soporta (muchas librerías ya deprecaron TLSv1.1 y TLSv1.2 en versiones recientes, por ejemplo

Comment: Tambien seria bueno saber que version de genexus estas utilizando. Podes ver este articulo por si ayuda: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39253,TLS%20Services

Comment: Olvide mencionar, es Gx17u4. Igualmente con el link que pasaste pude solucionar. Era el targetFramework que en el ambiente de test no estaba actualizado a 4.6.